# Ruby hash access value from string array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-2.3

I have an hash like below:

```
hash = {"a": [{"c": "d", "e": "f"}] }
```

Normally we can access it like `hash["a"][0]["c"]`.

But, I have a string like:

```
string = "a[0]['c']"
```

(This can change depending upon user input)

Is there any easy way to access hash using above string values?

Comment: Can the hash keys be anything, or is there some restriction  e.g. `a-zA-Z0-9_`?

Comment: For that matter, are the hash keys always symbols?

Comment: It can be anything

Comment: In that case, none of the answers below will work (although they're excellent for limited input) and you're going to have a difficult time coming up with one that works safely for "anything."

Comment: @Jordan Yes. To begin with I can restrict hash to symbol or index but later on I will need to find a solution for it.

Comment: You're basically going to build a Ruby parser, then. Also, I just noticed your question is inconsistent. In `hash` you use symbol keys (`{"c": "d"}` is equivalent to `{:c => "d"}`) but in `string` you have a string key `'c'`. How is that supposed to work?

Comment: If you could write `string = "[:a][0][:c]"`, which arguably is more appropriate than what you have, and you trust your data, you could write `eval ("hash" << string) #=> "d"`. Note that `"c": "d"` is the same as `c: "d"` or `:c => "d"`, so you don't need the quotes with the keys (unless you want to permit multiword keys, such as `:"my key"`). If you can't change the string format you could easily convert it to the above format in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the user inputs numbers for array indices and words for hash keys:

```
keys = string.scan(/(\d+)|(\w+)/).map do |number, string|
  number&.to_i || string.to_sym
end

hash.dig(*keys) # => "d"
```

Comment: Interesting example. I didn't know dig could iterate through a mix of Arrays and Hashes.

Comment: @EricDuminil, yea, it's awesome like that. It also works for structs. I really hope they add an `Indexible` module, where you have to implement `#[]` and it gives you other goodies like `#dig`.

Comment: @ndn You got me to wondering if `dig` will "dig" into any object that responds to `dig`—indeed it will! https://eval.in/691998 That's handy.

Comment: @Jordan, this is pretty much how it's implemented in the existing classes too. That is why I was hoping for an `Indexible` module in the future. (:

Comment: @ndn: I think your avatar is misleading. Maybe that's the goal, but your posts are good enough not to require this trick. My $0.02.

Comment: @EricDuminil, is there a scenario where I get to have a tick sign as an avatar and that is not a bad thing?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: @EricDuminil, can't a person just be a tick sign (✔)? :)

Comment: It doesn't make sense. I just find it suspiciously similar to the accepted answer sign.

Comment: @EricDuminil, that moment when your joke fails... In all seriousness, why does the tick sign avatar bother you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129938/discussion-between-eric-duminil-and-ndn).

Comment: @ndn: [Here's a start.](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11262#Related)

Comment: @JörgWMittag, awesome suggestion!

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Very interesting suggestion. I think you should find a better example than `%i[ruby c cplusplus scala java perl].select(&allowed_languages)` because it just does `%i[ruby c cplusplus scala java perl] & [:ruby, :python, :scala, :scheme]` with added complexity.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this :

```
hash = { 'a' => [{ 'c' => 'd', 'e' => 'f' }] }

string = "a[0]['c']"

def nested_access(object, string)
  string.scan(/\w+/).inject(object) do |hash_or_array, i|
    case hash_or_array
    when Array then hash_or_array[i.to_i]
    when Hash then hash_or_array[i] || hash_or_array[i.to_sym]
    end
  end
end

puts nested_access(hash, string) # => "d"
```

The input string is scanned for letters, underscores and digits. Everything else is ignored :

```
puts nested_access(hash, "a/0/c") #=> "d"
puts nested_access(hash, "a 0 c") #=> "d"
puts nested_access(hash, "a;0;c") #=> "d"
```

An incorrect access value will return nil.

It also works with symbol as keys :

```
hash = {a: [{c: "d", e: "f"}]}
puts nested_access(hash, "['a'][0]['c']")
```

It brings the advantage of being not too strict about user input, but it does have the drawback of not recognizing keys with spaces.

Comment: `{ "Hash keys aren't so \"predictable\"" => 1 }`

Comment: You're totally right, it won't work in this case. I fear that with a more restricted syntax, not many users, if any, would be able to use this key. Should the code be always correct but hard to use, or often correct and more forgiving of user input? That's for the OP to decide.

Comment: @EricDuminil The thing is user will input in a same way.
Like user will be given a hash and he has to input the path to reach a particular value.

Comment: @EricDuminil You're right, although the hash syntax is fine in Ruby 2.2+—`{"a": 1} == {a: 1} == {:a => 1}`. There's not really a good solution here if arbitrary hash keys are allowed. P.S. `\w` includes `_`, so `[\w_]` is redundant.

Comment: @Jordan : Thanks a lot. You're right, the hash syntax is correct for Ruby 2.3.1, but not Ruby 2.1.5.

Comment: @AbhishekJain: I don't understand your comment. Is there anything wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `gsub` to clean other characters into an array and use that array to access your hash

```
hash = {"a": [{"c": "d", "e": "f"}] }

string = "a[0]['c']"

tmp = string.gsub(/[\[\]\']/, '').split('')
#=> ["a", "0", "c"]

hash[tmp[0].to_sym][tmp[1].to_i][tmp[2].to_sym]
#=> "d"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, it is not necessary that the second argument is an integer. Above one is just an example and hash and input string can be in any form.